# Create files with exact name as in a given directory

Tags: command-line, bash, zsh

Say there is a directory `foo` where there are files:

```
$ ls
001.mp4
002.mp4
```

While being in another directory `bar` I'd like to have the same files as in `bar` but empty. What have I tried so far:

When in `bar` I execute:

```
$ find ../foo -type f |xargs -0
```

I get:

```
../foo/001.mp4
../foo/002.mp4
```

This gives me a list of files but with relative path while I need only filenames (with extensions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the job:

While in `bar` run the following command changing `/PATH_TO/foo/` with the real path to `foo`:

```
ls -p /PATH_TO/foo/ | grep -v / | tr [:blank:] '_' | xargs touch
```

---

> Explaination:
>
> - `ls -p` will list all the *files and directories* in the path directory and the option `-p` will add a `/` to the directory names.
> - `tr [:blank:] '_'` will replace each space in the file names with `_` or otherwise `touch` might fail to create such files with spaces in their names.
> - `grep -v /` will exclude directories by removing all items containing a `/` in their names leaving only file names in the output.
> - `xargs touch` will create empty files in `bar` with names duplicated from all file names found in `foo`.

---

**Notice:**

In some cases [parsing the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) might be better avoided.

Comment: Great. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe more simple way exists, but here how I'm getting the result you expect:

```
find ../foo -type f | while read i ; do basename "$i" ; done
```

Comment: Nice. How do I use your answer to create empty files (`touch` comes to mind)?

Comment: With `find ../foo -type f | while read i ; do touch $(basename "$i") ; done` (be careful from where you run this command).

Comment: I run this command in a directory where I wanted files to be created. Unfortunately, I did not the trick - no file was created.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
find ../foo -type f -exec sh -c 'touch $(basename {})' \;
```

Comment: I get `sh: command substitution: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('`.

Comment: I tested the command and had no errors, are you shure you typed it correctly?

Comment: I realize now that you are using zsh... I'm using bash, I really don't know if the command is compatible.